# How to extract two numbers from input line and tab delimit them?

Tags: python, string, input, split, line

```
myString = "Exon        51 100.0 1446231 1446281 NW_003101558.1     1    51 XM_002612573.1  Branchiostoma floridae hypothetical protein, mRNA"  
print myString.split('100.0')[1].split(" ")[2]
```

This is where I got stuck. I would like to get both numbers from the second split ("1446231 1446281"), but I only get the second one.

Ideally i would like "Exon 1446231 1446281" as the output - all tab delimited. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store the result of the `split()` call, so you can access the elements you need.

Then you can then join those elements together with [`join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> myString = "Exon        51 100.0 1446231 1446281 NW_003101558.1     1    51
XM_002612573.1  Branchiostoma floridae hypothetical protein, mRNA"
>>> s = myString.split()
>>> print '\t'.join((s[0], s[3], s[4]))
Exon    1446231 1446281
>>>
```

For more complex scenarios, a single split is probably not sufficient, but you'll get the idea.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like that you have a variable number of white spaces that separate different fields of your string, use the regular expressions to split your string.

```
import re
s = re.split('\s+', myString)
print '\t'.join([s[0], s[3], s[4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution in one line :

```
>>> print '\t'.join([y for x,y in enumerate(myString.split()) if x in (0,3,4)])
Exon    1446231 1446281
>>>
```